# got Error upgrading parity data: CannotUpdateVersionFile running parity 1.6

Tags: parity

I launch my parity node as usual and get

```
Error upgrading parity data: CannotUpdateVersionFile
```

on startup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it turns out that this was a `disk full` message